Loops and UV divergences
I read when asked whether a force could only exist at a certain phase transition or high energy:

"I am not aware of a coupling that only exists at high energies or in a phase transition -- in the examples I know of, if a coupling at all then it always exists in some form. But supposing you could make such a coupling, loop contributions are off shell, so there will presumably be some part of the integral that has the kinematics you need to make the interaction exist, so the contribution will be nonzero. In other words, you have particles of arbitrarily high energy running in loops (hence UV divergences). But, the contribution will be small, if the energies needed are large.".

Question. What does it mean "particles of arbitrarily high energy running in loops"? And if there were UV divergences, why is the contribution small if the energies needed are large?

For the first part of your question, a typical 1-loop integral with cutoff regularization at some momentum cutoff $\Lambda$ might look like
$$
\int_{|p| < \Lambda} \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} F(p; m, g, k)
$$
where the integrand $F(p; m, g, k)$ is some function of the loop momentum, as well as masses $m$, couplings $g$, and external momenta $k$. Typically it will be some kind of product of propagators and coupling constants.
The phrase "arbitrarily high momenta run in the loop" means that the loop momenta $p$ have a magnitude less than the cutoff $\Lambda$ (here we imagine we have done a Wick rotation and work with Euclidean). Since we will take $\Lambda\rightarrow \infty$ at the end, the magnitude of $p$ can become arbitrarily large.
The second part of the question is much trickier. If arbitrarily large energies appear in loop integrals, why do they not contribute significantly to low energy processes? The short answer is the decoupling theorem, and effective field theory. Essentially, the effect of the high energy modes can be absorbed into a renormalization of bare coupling constants for local operators. Or, from a Wilsonian point of view, as you integrate out high energy modes, the effect is to change the coefficients of operators in the Wilson action, and ultimately only the relevant and marginal operators matter at low energies. This is not trivial and the subject of textbooks, so I'm not going to try to give a more technical explanation than that, but one resource I liked in grad school is this one by Cliff Burgess: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701053

Why did you mention about high energy processes? Was it because I mentioned about phase transition? My original thought was what if there is dark matter counterpart to the electromagnetism that can make Maxwell Equation symmetric with existence of magnetic monopoles located in the dark matter sector. And you can only bind them together by some low energy couping process. If this is so, then no need for all those descriptions about high energy and UV divergences. Right?

@Jtl At some point you said: "If say dark matter only couples to matter at high energies...". The only point I was trying to make is that I do not know of any example of a particle that couples to other particles only at high energies (and not also at low energies).

I read a scientist proposing consciousness can couple ordinary electromagnetism and dark monopoles recovering symmetry in maxwell equations. And he had experiments to prove it. Let us say it was true. It is either the force can also couple them at high energies or it cant be considered a force but another name that wont affect the running of physical constants?
